# Publishing Site - multiple 'Pages' library

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, publishing-page

I tried creating a regular document library with content types using my custom page layout. Each time I try to make a new page from within the new library, I get the error message. The page layout template works if used in default `Pages` library.

```
Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred.
TECHNICAL DETAILS

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 9a438a9e-c0ae-6000-86a1-078208c1cd08

Date and Time: 8/31/2018 3:13:58 PM

GO BACK TO SITE
```

<del>If above is not possible, how do I add a web part using the `Pages` library. I'm trying to see if I can easily add dynamic table of contents or related links. The `Pages` library is not visible from the list of apps.</del>

Comment: Pages library is not visible to you?? Which permissions do you have on site?

Comment: No, I wasn't until after I deactivated and activated the publishing feature once more. I can see it now.  But, is there a way to create a separate library while using  the custom page layout without getting the error message above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate the publishing feature to see the Pages Library in Site contents.

Steps to Activate:

```
1. Go to site Settings

2. Click on Site collection features



     https://Yoursite.com/sites/yourwebsite/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site

3. Activate the feature "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"
```

Once Feature activated you will be able to see the Page Library

Comment: it was already activated. I deactivated and activated it again and I can see `Pages` from the list of apps from the insert web part option. Thanks.